# How can I save a watermark on PDF File and export to Desktop macOS Mojave

Tags: swift, cocoa, pdf

I have an app running in macOS Mojave and it works nicely. I can drag a pdf file onto a PDFView and can put a button to mark a watermark on the pdf file. I got the example code from apple WWDC written for iOS, and I translated it for macOS. My problem is how can I save this pdf including the watermark, to desktop for example?

---

My Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pdfView?.acceptsDraggedFiles = true
}

func classForPage() -> AnyClass {
    return WatermarkPage.self
}

@IBAction func WaterMark(_ sender: NSButton) {
    if let document = PDFDocument(url:  (pdfView?.document?.documentURL)!){

    //Center document on gray background
    pdfView?.autoScales = true
    pdfView?.backgroundColor = NSColor.lightGray

    // 1. Set delegate
    document!.delegate = self   
    pdfView?.document = document

    let filename: String = "ExportPDF.pdf"
    let path =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask,
                                                true)[0];
    let writePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).appendingPathComponent(filename).path
    //pdfView?.document?.write(toFile: writePath)
    document?.write(toFile: writePath)
    print("Pfad: \(path)")
    }
}

class WatermarkPage: PDFPage {
    // 3. Override PDFPage custom draw
    /// - Tag: OverrideDraw
    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, to context: CGContext) {


        // Draw original content
        super.draw(with: box, to: context)

        // Draw rotated overlay string
        context.saveGState()

        let pageBounds = self.bounds(for: box)
        context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageBounds.size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.rotate(by: CGFloat.pi / 5.0)

        let string: NSString = "A P P R O V E D"

        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor(calibratedRed: 0.8, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5),NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 64.0)]
        string.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 40), withAttributes: attributes)

        context.restoreGState()
        context.saveGState()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys sorry that was a total misunderstanding of mine. Total error of reason. I can watermark the document then I can just save it or print it and the watermark will be present. I do not need a separate save function. Ou man I make my head so good sometimes you sit on the hose. Thank you very much for your great help.